# Is there any subsitute of PHP function random_bytes(32) in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I want to generate byte code in ColdFusion 18 but not able to generate. Binary data can be generate in multiple ways.

In PHP when we use this function random_bytes(32), We get output like

`�]�[AH��2H�˖�b��|m���j )��ʻ��`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2976-trying-to-generate-cryptographically-strong-random-tokens-in-coldfusion.htm

Comment: Maybe look at the implementation of https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat ? It's a polyfill for the inbuild `random_bytes` function.